# getting Fatal error of PDO::fetchColumn()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a small function to count rows in a table, but when I run the function, I am getting *"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object in P:\wamp\www\test\class\db.class.php on line 34"*. Below is my code:

```
<?php
class db {
    public $pdo;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . database_name . ";host=" . database_host . "", database_user, database_pass, array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
        ));
    }


    public function countdata($field, $table, $where = "1") {
        $ar = $this->pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(`".$field."`) FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE " . $where . "");
        $cnt=$ar->fetchColumn(0);
        return $cnt;
    }
?>
```

Comment: -1. As I told you before, you **don't** need such a function, for many reasons. Having it violates many essential laws.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am a learner, so may you please tell me how I can count rows as a function, as I donot want to type code everytime ..

Comment: I posted an answer with an explanation to your other question already. Why tell anything if you don't read anyway? show me at least one case where you think you need this function and I'll show you it is totally useless and you can go without it

Comment: the error you are getting now is a **direct consequence** of this function's bad design.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $cnt=$ar->fetch();
```

Or this by giving an alias

```
   $ar = $this->pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(`".$field."`) as counts FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE " . $where . ""); 
   $cnt=$ar->fetchColumn(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you Might want to make sure `$db-query()`
You should check that your call to `$db->query` returns a valid PDO object

Comment: I can assure you it doesn't return a valid PDO [statement] object

Comment: yes sir you right @ Your Common Sense .i just told to check ...and you gave me down-vote for that :(